# How to hook into two datasets in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have two datasets defined which are retrieving data from 2 databases.
For a table column, i want to simply switch between 2 datasets to pick value.
My table is retrieving data from one dataset.So for a column;

eg:

```
=IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value=40, Fields!SiteCode.Value,

SecondDataset.SiteCode.value)
```

How can i do that?  I checked Lookup function, but I'm not sure how that is useful here?

Comment: Need more context here.. is it a simple text box or a detail line that you are using your IIF statement in?

Comment: @Harry It is for textbox, or for columns of the table

Comment: if you are wanting to populate a column then lookup is exactly what you want.. you just need to wrap the iff around look up

Comment: @Harry Can you give me an example for this simple scenario with Lookup?, Why it looks for 4 parameters..I dont understand that

Comment: you don't need 4 parameters.. look at the example for lookup.. think of it like a SQL JOIN between the 2 datasets 

=Lookup(Fields!Fields!SiteCode.Value, Fields!Fields!SiteCode.Value,  Fields!Fields!SiteCode.Value, "dataset2")

Comment: @Harry, Why 3 times mentioning Sitecode ? That is why I didnt understand?Can you write your comment as answer with clear explanation?

Comment: it's like this.. use the first field value, "Join" on the second field value (from the second dataset) and return the third field value from the second dataset.. makes sense? substitute the third field value with another field from the second dataset and you will see how it works

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by putting the lookup in your IIF statement. Assuming the SiteCode depends on the CompanyID:

```
=IIF(Parameters!CompanyId.Value=40, Fields!SiteCode.Value,lookup(Parameters!CompanyId.Value,Fields!CompanyId.Value,Fields!SiteCode.Value))
```

If it's more complicated than this, we would need information on the table you are looking up in.